# Second click funcktion on a div?

Tags: javascript

On the first click the `div` should become red and I want it to become white on the second click but I do not know how. I need code that makes the `div` white on the second click.

```
function red() {
    document.getElementById("red").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: use a class to style the element and toggle it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/erLh4fcz/1/ - [in modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: If it's white by default, @ArunPJohny 's suggestion is the right one, and toggling the class is the easiest way. If you have an array of colors to go through, store the current 'position' as a data attribute on the element, and get the color from the array based on this position, and increment the position

Comment: Use `classList.toggle`, check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5v421qv3/)

Comment: Ok i'll try it. Thx!

Comment: I think ArunPJohny's fiddle answers it, but just in case you want to toggle through more then 1 color (so white is not the starting color) you can use something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lqj6qgw9/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Var colors[]=["red","white",...];    //colors that are to be selected in order.
Var clicked=0;                       // no. Of clicks
//call this function when the div is clicked like this <div onclick="changeColor()" .....
function changeColor(){

    document.getElementById(divId).style.background =colors[clicked];                                                 //change color according to clicks

    clicked++;                 // increase no. Of clicks by 1

    /*if you want to repeat the pattern */
    if(colors.length==clicked){
        clicked=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to the element and use jquery toggleClass for more detail read [this](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: where is jQuery in tags

Comment: yes thats why i am suggesting to user jquery rather than javascript.

Comment: When suggesting jQuery, at least give a reasoning as to why you would use it. In this case, the same function exists in native javascript. If jQuery isn't needed for the rest of the website, including jQuery just slows things down unnecesarily.

Comment: @DrunkWolf "including jQuery just slows things down unnecesarily" I think you may want to read up on complexity versus complexity. The reason most people choose to use jQuery is the same reason why most don't program computers in raw 1s and 0s: it provides a useful and consistent abstraction, and 99.99% of the time, any performance loss is negated by the productivity gains.

Comment: Nice job taking half the sentence out of context there. Ofcourse jQuery is amazing and it or something similar gives advantages in larger projects. That doesn't mean it's an autoinclude on sites that only use 2-3 lines of javascript total. And that said, i never said OP shouldnt use jquery, i merely said that you should give reasoning as to WHY in your answer (and preferably also give the equivalent non-jQuery code).